# Which android permission is better for Bluetooth device discovery or receiving Bluetooth broadcast?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-manifest, android-permissions, broadcast

I am getting permission issues while trying for Bluetooth device discovery.

Issue:-**"requires android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION due to sender com.android.bluetooth"** already added the following permissions to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: can you show your logcat?

Comment: system_process W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND flg=0x10 (has extras) } to ProcessRecord{4317e49 12622:xxxxx/u0a26} (pid=12622, uid=10026) requires android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION due to sender com.android.bluetooth (uid 1002)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct procedure for BT device discovery on Marshmallow is as follows:

1) Have ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission requirement in manifest along with usual bluetooth permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

2)Ensure you have run-time permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

```
protected void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                   String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            proceedDiscovery(); // --->
        } else {
            //TODO re-request
        }
        break;
    }
}
}
```

3) Register a broadcast receiver for ACTION_FOUND and call

```
BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()
protected void proceedDiscovery() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_NAME_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
}
```

Comment: accept my answer by clicking on TICK on the left side of the answer if this helped you :)

Comment: thanks, I think after add the call to checkLocationPermissions , it works

Comment: but the question I have is , not all android things device will with a touch screen , how that permission can be granted ?

Comment: using buttons .

Comment: sorry, did not get it , if not touch screen,  define GPIO to grant permission ?